# javascript enum to convert to list and check if the value is present in that enum

Tags: javascript, list, enums

lets say i have an enum in javascript defined like this:

```
const myEnum = {
    A:'a',
    B:'b',
    C:'c',
    D:'d'
};
```

I have a character and I need to check whether it is present in the enum or not.

currently, I'm doing something like

```
if(value !== myEnum.A || value !==myEnum.B || ......) {
   //FAILURE
}
```

this is something of a problem how do I make it something like:

```
if(value not in myEnum.values){
   //FAILURE
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Object.values to check this

```
if (!Object.values(myEnum).includes(value)) {
    // Do what you want here
}
```

```js
const myEnum = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b',
    C: 'c',
    D: 'd'
};

console.log(Object.values(myEnum).includes('a'));
console.log(Object.values(myEnum).includes('v'));
```